# PHP pallant/laravel-aws-cognito-auth - Out of memory

Tags: php, laravel-5, amazon-cognito

I am getting following error even I use php memory limit to -1 (no limit)
(1/1)

`FatalErrorException Out of memory (allocated 509607936) (tried to allocate 501223424 bytes)in HomeController.php (line 36)`

```
 <?php
 try { 
    Auth::attempt([ 'email' => 'pppppp@live.com', 
                    'password' => 'pppppp'
                  ]
                  false,
                  AWS_COGNITO_AUTH_THROW_EXCEPTION); 
} catch (\Pallant\LaravelAwsCognitoAuth\AuthAttemptException $e) { 
    $response = $e->getResponse(); var_export($response); 
    /* Handle error... */
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have anything extra installed with composer?Like debugbar or clockwork?

Comment: Is the `var_export` the call that actually exhausts memory?

Comment: @ficuscr, checking the docs, it does mention the parsed object needs to implement the magic __set_state method, which might not be the case with the $response.@waleed,what happens if you dump($response); instead?

Comment: No, I mean more like `mb_strlen(serialize($response), '8bit') > 500MB` approximately... Are you simply getting a that error because of your dump. Red herring.

Comment: @RobBiermann ahh took me a minute. You are also correct... depending on what `response` is `var_export` might not be... well happy... it's more like a `serialize` than a dump call isn't it.

Comment: True, I think that would be a better solution, i'm just getting too used to using dump() for troubleshoots :P

Comment: thanks guys, memory issue is due to var_export, but aws cognito is not working, looking into it.